# Which topic(s) does this matrix come from? What is the name of this matrix?

Tags: matrices

Which topic(s) does this matrix come from? What is the name of this matrix?

$$\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&\omega&\omega^2\\1&\omega^2&\omega}$$

Comment: That's a Vandermonde matrix, as well as the matrix of the discrete Fourier transform of size $3$... It is not quite clear what the purpose of this question is, though!

Comment: We are assuming that $\omega$ here is a root of unity, of course (too bad OP did not define his/her notation)... if not, then it's just some symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 7):

This is the [discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) matrix of size $3$. It naturally appears mathematically in the [representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory) (don't be intimidated by this!) of the cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, as well as practically in [signal processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing) and related fields.